# hr tag shows a line in 2 colors against a colored background

Tags: html, css, colors, background-color

I use a hr tag. It was working well, untl I gave the text a colored background. Now I see a white line under the black line. How to see only the black line?

```css
div {
  background-color: #eab126;
  min-height: 100px;
}

hr {
  height: 1px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div>
    Testing<br />
    Testing<br />

  <hr />

Testing<br />
Testing<br />

</div>
```

[image: This is what the hr looks like]

Comment: `hr { border-top: 0;border-bottom: #fff 1px solid; }`

Comment: if you want to know the *why*, it's because the default style is set to `inset` which create an effect with two colors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the CSS for the `hr` tag,

HTML 5 Boilerplate project in its default stylesheet [specifies](https://github.com/paulirish/html5-boilerplate/blob/ef3c095bafa9a6fa9c771f368d4b30c8ce4deded/css/style.css#L75) the following rule:

```
hr { display: block; height: 1px;
border: 0; border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
margin: 1em 0; padding: 0; }
```

```css
div {
  background-color: #eab126;
  min-height: 100px;
}

hr {
  display: block;
  height: 1px;
  border: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid white;
  margin: 1em 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Testing<br /> Testing
  <br />

  <hr /> Testing

  <br /> Testing
  <br />

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the colour of the `hr` you use `border-color` not `color`.

To change the height of the `hr` manipulate the border width(s):

```css
div {
  background-color: #eab126;
  min-height: 100px;
}

hr {
  border-color: black;
  border-top-width: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Testing<br /> Testing
  <br />

  <hr /> Testing

  <br /> Testing
  <br />

</div>
```